# Using double pointers in C

Tags: c, getline, pointer-to-pointer

Am doing a task where am supposed to used getline function read input from a user from the terminal. Here is my code:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
        printf("Write something: \n");
        char **buf = NULL;
        size_t buf_size = 0;

        ssize_t bytes_read = getline(buf, &buf_size, stdin);
        if (bytes_read != -1)
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf,  buf_size);
        else
                printf("An error occured\n");
        free(buf);
        return (0);
}
```

From the code above. My program displayed the text: An error occurred.
Did some code refactoring and this is what I came up with:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
        printf("Write something: \n");
        char *buf = NULL;
        size_t buf_size = 0;

        ssize_t bytes_read = getline(&buf, &buf_size, stdin);
        if (bytes_read != -1)
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf,  buf_size);
        else
                printf("An error occured\n");
        free(buf);
        return (0);
}
```

Voila! The code displayed whatever was inputted, just what I wanted. So I fixed my the issue. But what am trying to understand is what's wrong the first code snippet? An it is right to do this?:
`char **name = "John Doe";`
or
`char **name = NULL;`

I did some quick test on an online compiler. Here is the code:

```
int main() {
    // Write C code here
    char **name = "John Doe";
    printf("%p\n", name); //0x55f5f9890004
    printf("%p\n", *name); //0x656f44206e686f4a
    printf("%c\n", *name); //J
    printf("%p", "John Doe"); //0x55f5f9890004

    return 0;
}
```

I realised that the double pointer was just treated as a single char pointer. Not sure if my finding are right. If you can give a better explanation the above main function that would be cool.

Comment: You need to turn up compiler warnings and read them - then you will be informed that things like `char **name = "John Doe";` are in fact not okay to do and invoke *undefined behavior* down the line

Comment: @UnholySheep. I used these flags when compling: gcc -Wall -Werror -pedantic . But got no error

Comment: (1) It is not enough to know the type of the argument. You need to read the documentation to understand what kind of value is expected. (2) A pointer argument with the value of NULL, if allowed, generally means " this is an optional argument and in this case I am not supplying a meaningful value; this is effectively ignored". Can the first argument of `getline` be of this nature?

Comment: @n.m. As detailed by the documentation https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html, the *first_argument(buffer) can be NULL. So, what the function does is that it allocates memory the buffer

Comment: Yes, `*first_argument` can be NULL. Does `char **buf = NULL;` do that? What is `*buf` in this case?

Comment: @n.m I have now understood what you are saying. Thank you for pointing that out, seems I wasn't keen when reading the documentation. (*buf will be invalid, right?)

Comment: Yes that's right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to change a variable in a function you need to pass it by reference. Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of the value of the original object used as an argument expression and changing the copy of the value will not influence on the value of the original object.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it.

Thus dereferencing the pointer the function will have a direct access to the original object and can change it.

In this code snippet

```
    char *buf = NULL;                                                                                                                                       
    size_t buf_size = 0;                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                            
    ssize_t bytes_read = getline(&buf, &buf_size, stdin);
```

you want that the pointer `buf` after calling the function `getline` would point to a string read in the function. So you need to pass it to the function by reference the same way as you are passing another variable `buf_size` the value of which is also changed within the function and the caller of the function needs to know the result value of the variable.

If you will write

```
    char **buf = NULL;                                                                                                                                       
    size_t buf_size = 0;                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                            
    ssize_t bytes_read = getline(buf, &buf_size, stdin);
```

then the function within itself will try to dereference the null pointer `buf` that results in undefined behavior because it thinks that the so-called "double pointer" points to an object of the type `char *` that the function needs to change.

To make it more clear consider the following demonstration programs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( char *s )
{
    s = "World!";
}

int main( void )
{
    char *s = "Hello";

    printf( "Before calling f s = %s\n", s );

    f( s );

    printf( "After  calling f s = %s\n", s );
}
```

The program output is

```
Before calling f s = Hello
After  calling f s = Hello
```

The pointer `s` passed to the function be value. That is the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer. Changing the copy does not influence on the original value of the pointer `s`.

Now consider the next program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( char **s )
{
    *s = "World!";
}

int main( void )
{
    char *s = "Hello";

    printf( "Before calling f s = %s\n", s );

    f( &s );

    printf( "After  calling f s = %s\n", s );
}
```

The program output is

```
Before calling f s = Hello
After  calling f s = World!
```

That is as the pointer s is passed to the function by reference the function can change the original pointer `s` by dereferencing the pointer passed to the function that points to the original pointer `s`.
As for this declaration

```
char **name = "John Doe";
```

then the compiler should issue a message that declaration is wrong. The string literal used as an initializer is implicitly converted tp pointer to its first element of the type `char *`. But the initialized variable has the type `char **` and there is no implicit conversion between these pointer types.

Also the conversion specifier `%s` expects an argument of the type  `char *` instead of the type `char **`.

So you have to write

```
char *name = "John Doe";
```

Or as you may not change a string literal then it will be better to write the declaration like

```
const char *name = "John Doe";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought I understood pointer, but it seems I haven't. Just leant something about pointer by reference vs by value

Answer (score 0):

In the `char *buf` case, `getline` will go to the memory location of the pointer `buf` and change that address.

In case of `char **buf = NULL;`, `getline` will go the memory location "null" and try to change that address, which is nonsense. You essentially lie to `getline` and tell it that you stored a pointer for it at memory location "null".

As for `char **name = "John Doe";` it is a constraint violation of C's assignment rules, anything can happen since the code isn't valid C. Including "seems to work fine all the way until the mysterious crash some years later in live production code". You might want to take the skunk out of that online compiler by for example applying [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 0):

A double pointer has to reference a valid pointer to work (as that pointer will store the reference to the newly allocated memory.

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
        printf("Write something: \n");
        char *realBuf = NULL
        char **buf = &realBuf;
        size_t buf_size = 0;

        ssize_t bytes_read = getline(buf, &buf_size, stdin);
        if (bytes_read != -1)
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, *buf,  buf_size);
        else
                printf("An error occured\n");
        free(*buf);
        return (0);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There are no “double pointers” in C, so you cannot use them.

But for any type T, you can create a type “pointer to T”. And that’s the case if T is a pointer type as well. That’s a pointer to a pointer. Not a “double pointer”. If you see char** as a “double pointer” you will forever be confused.

Comment: Well there is `double*` :)